# How to rename a table inside a schema?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.x, I want to rename a table.  This SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE new (id int);
ALTER TABLE new RENAME TO old;
DROP TABLE old;
```

renames the table correctly.  But this SQL code:

```
CREATE SCHEMA domain;
CREATE TABLE domain.old (id int);
ALTER TABLE domain.old RENAME TO domain.new;
```

fails, with error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "."

The "." underlined is the one between 'domain' and 'new'

Answer (score 174, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE domain.old RENAME TO new
```

Other way:

```
SET search_path TO domain;
ALTER TABLE old RENAME TO new;
```

Documentation for [`search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html).

Comment: thx that works for general purpose but my current case is a little more complex... following refactoring consisting into naming tables with singular names, i want to rename domain.users to domain.user ! with SET, I have to write ALTER TABLE users RENAME TO 'user'; but neither '' nor [] notation work with RENAME TO seems... I got a syntax error in both cases... any clue ?

Comment: @comte Added one more solution, which is a one liner (it is the same as you original one, just don't specify the schema for old, it will stay the same)

Comment: your one liner works perfectly with any non-reserved tablename as new name. Same, it won't work with reserved keyword between '' or []

Comment: my mistake : we have to use double-quotes for reserved words in postgresql, not single quote or brackets. ALTER TABLE domain.users RENAME TO "user"; solves my problem.

Comment: @comte: the double quotes for identifiers are required by the SQL standard and this is well documented in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS Not sure why you find that suprising

Comment: if you have time to polemics, you should have read in my remarks that I also tried brackets, that are convention on some other SQL engines (MS products such as SQL Server at least), and that single-quotes, brackets, double-quotes are also allowed by others (SQL Lite for instance). You're correct to say that double-quotes are SQL-92 standard, but then the question is : does postgresql comply 100% to SQL standard. AFAIK, like many engines, answer is negative.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET search_path TO domain;
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS old_table_name RENAME TO new_table_name;
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Switch to your database

```
machine$\c my_database
```

2. Tename the db

```
my_databse=# alter table old_name rename to new_name;
```